# oVirt engine 3.6 in local Internet **connectionless** network

Tags: centos, virtualization, ovirt

I wanna use oVirt engine 3.6 in my Internet connectionless network. I installed oVirt with yum over internet. After that I tried to work offline. When I go offline Web Interface it still works fine. But I connected it to my local netowork Interface starts not to respond. I check POST/GET requests that made by it and I see it stuck on request/respond to/from GenericApiGWTService. For example, normally time between request and respond takes 1 to 600ms but when I connect it to local network it take up to 300.000ms second and eventually it fails. I use CentOS 7 x86_64. I couldn't figure out what is it cause to that.

Comment: are you using an internal DNS server and the engine and hosts are resolvable?

Comment: There is no local DNS and all host are managed by static IPs so no need for domain name resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by;

- Use another IP from different address group then the one you use for internet connection. Example: I used 192.168.1.10 for internet connection. When I connect pc to local I changed it to 192.168.2.10
- Delete all Gateway and DNS IPs.

Then it works fine.